Angular 17: auto-append section to every page (component) in section
I'm building a multi-page site in Angular 17. I have 4 main sections, each with their own unique subnav. At the moment, I'm manually adding the subnav component to each HTML template in the section, but it's somewhat bothersome to have to do that manually. Is it possible to have one HTML template inherit from another HTML template? Here's a screenshot of what I currently have:

At the moment there's nothing in the tools page or tools subnav components.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tools-page',
  templateUrl: './tools-page.component.html',
  styleUrl: './tools-page.component.scss'
})
export class ToolsPageComponent {}

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tools-subnav',
  templateUrl: './tools-subnav.component.html',
  styleUrl: './tools-subnav.component.scss'
})
export class ToolsSubnavComponent {}

This is all there is in the tools-page-component.html file:
<app-tools-subnav></app-tools-subnav>

This is what the tools-create-topic-header.html component HTML file looks like:
<app-tools-subnav></app-tools-subnav>
<div class="main">
    <h2>Create Topic Header</h2>
    ...
</div>

So what I'm asking is if there's a way to somehow have the subnav be automatically appended to the section HTML files, or those sub components could somehow inherit from the "main" tools component causing the subnav to be added automatically.

You can do it via Routing, Create a warpper component, that will have the tools header and a router-outlet, now all the child routes, will inherit the parent html, as shown below
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: '',
        component: WrapperComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'one',
            component: OneComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'two',
            component: TwoComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'one',
            pathMatch: 'full',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ]),
  ],
});

MAIN:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, RouterLink, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { WrapperComponent } from './app/wrapper/wrapper.component';
import { OneComponent } from './app/one/one.component';
import { TwoComponent } from './app/two/two.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
  template: `
    <a [routerLink]="'/one'">one</a>  | <a [routerLink]="'/two'">two</a>
    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: '',
        component: WrapperComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'one',
            component: OneComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'two',
            component: TwoComponent,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'one',
            pathMatch: 'full',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ]),
  ],
});

WRAPPER:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { ToolbarComponent } from '../toolbar/toolbar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wrapper',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ToolbarComponent, RouterOutlet],
  template: `<app-toolbar />
  <p>wrapper works!</p>
  <router-outlet />`,
})
export class WrapperComponent {}

COMPONENT:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-two',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `<p>two works!</p>`,
})
export class TwoComponent {}

TOOLBAR:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `<p>toolbar works!</p>`,
})
export class ToolbarComponent {}

Stackblitz Demo

Naren, thanks for your thorough reply. I've got a few questions though. I specifically built my app with standalone=false because that's the most similar to the app I work on for my job. Could you offer insight as to which parts of your answer need to be updated? For example, I got an error indicating that imports is not allowed in components that are not standalone.

@commadelimited Then all you need to do is, ignore the imports array and add the component to your declarations array of the module you are using and the code will work fine! but the concept stays the same for template like inheritance!

Nice, thank you. I'll test this out tonight, then accept this as the answer after I've confirmed.

Thank you Naren. I ended up going the easy route and creating a single navbar with dropdowns, instead of the double layered nav like in my original post. I upvoted, but since I didn't use your suggestion I'm not selecting it as the answer.

@commadelimited no problem!
